# Random Forest Classifier - Convert Indexed Label tag back to String value

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am doing a text classification and I have built a model using the pipeline method.

I am fitting my training data which I have created using a dataframe and it has the columns "labels" and "sentences". The labels have different question types. The DF looks like,

```
training = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
("DESC:manner", "How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia ?"),
("DESC:def", "What does '' extended definition '' mean and how would one a paper on it ? "),
("HUM:ind", " Who was The Pride of the Yankees ?")
], ["label", "sentence"])
```

The code for creating the pipeline is -

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(training) 
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=20)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="idxlabel")

rf = RandomForestClassifier().setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("idxlabel") 
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, idf, indexer, rf])
model = pipeline.fit(training)
```

And code for predicting is -

```
test = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("What is the highest waterfall in the United States ?" ,)], ["sentence"])
prediction = model.transform(test)
selected = prediction.select("sentence", "prediction")
```

Now if I give the command 'selected.show(truncate=False)' then it is showing the data in following format -

```
+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
|Question                                            |prediction|
+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
|What is the highest waterfall in the United States ?|2.0       |
+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

The problem is that I want the predicted data to be in label format as it was in training data. But I am getting the value in double format. How can I convert the predicted value from double to string back?

Answer (score 3):

There is an IndexToString transformer that provides the required functionality. See scala example in Spark sources for details: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/RandomForestClassifierExample.scala

```
labeler = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="predictedLabel", labels=indexer.labels)
```